Как можно убрать эти ошибки в коде?
Вот код:
plugins {
id("com.android.application") version "6.3.0" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.10" apply false

Вот ошибка:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram20\build.gradle.kts' line: 1
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '6.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '6.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:


А правильно указан плагин и его версия?  В Maven Repository версии 5.x/6.x отсутствуют.  Может следовало указать версию 8.3.0?
